# Python - Efficient way to read large amounts of tabular data

Tags: python, optimization

I have a file containing a large table of numbers, roughly 300 MB in size.  I want to read this in Python.

Data looks like this:

```
-200 1 11097.4 16414.2 1
-200 1 11197.4 16414.8 1
-200 1 11297.4 16415.4 1
-200 1 11397.4 16416 1
-200 1 11497.4 16416.5 1
-200 1 11597.4 16417.1 1
-200 1 11697.4 16417.7 1
```

Python code looks like this:

```
    with open(filename) as f:
        nrow, ncol= [int(x) for x in next(f).split()] 
        for k in range(2):
            rr = []
            for i in range(nrow+1):
                row = []
                for j in range(ncol+1):
                    a = next(f).split()                     
                    row.append([int(a[0]), int(a[1]), float(a[2]), float(a[4])])
                rr.append(row)          
            summary.append(rr)
```

This is very slow; it takes about 60 seconds to read the file.  I want to get it down to less than 10 seconds.  What's the simplest way to make it a bit faster?

I am perfectly happy to change the data file format, if it helps.

Comment: Have you looked at pandas?

Comment: never heard of pandas, will google, thanks!

Comment: I think you maybe read data wrong with all these three nested loops. what are values `nrow` and `ncol` that you read from the first line of the file?

Comment: It is correct, the table is 2*nrow*ncol entries, and each entry has 5 numbers written in one line.

Comment: OK, if you are certain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pandas. This might be a duplicate so also check out these answers

- [Read a large csv into a sparse pandas dataframe in a memory efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888856/read-a-large-csv-into-a-sparse-pandas-dataframe-in-a-memory-efficient-way)
- [How do I read CSV data into a record array in NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy/26296194#26296194)

### code.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("large_file.txt", sep="\s")
np.save("large_file.npz", df.values)

with load('large_file.npz') as data:
    print(data.shape)
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate this response, but unfortunately it still takes forever (minutes) to read the file.  It is largely the parsing that is a problem, even in C it takes a long time unless I change the data format to a binary one.  Is there an equivalent or similar solution in python?

Comment: If you want the whole thin in memory at the same time then that is your only option, if you can read it in by parts then pass in the chunksize.

Comment: Also you can read it from multiple cores but this problem might just be I/O bound.

Comment: You can try and save/load in a different format. Try using numpy's save and load. You can save the .values into a file and see how long that takes to load.

Comment: numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (2, 5001, 1501, 4) and data type float64

Comment: It seems numpy runs out of memory.